# org.json.JSONException: Value OR-12345 at order_no of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, android

I am trying to populate the recycler view using json data from dummy api but it is not working. I have tried almost several solutions given in stack overflow.

Here is my code below:

```
public class loadOrdersList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        ordersList = new ArrayList<>();
        rvor = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_orders);
        rvor.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvor.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(OrdersActivity.this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

        if (new CheckNetworkUtil(OrdersActivity.this).isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Log.d("TEST", "------------------ordersList: " + ordersList.size());
        OrdersAdapter adapter = new OrdersAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ordersList);
        rvor.setAdapter(adapter);
            srl.setRefreshing(false);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(OrdersActivity.this, "No Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://api.myjson.com/bins/la2gh")
                        .build();

                Response responses = client.newCall(request).execute();

                JSONArray orders = new JSONArray(responses.body().string());

                ordersList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < orders.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject name = orders.getJSONObject(i);
                    String customerName = name.getString("customer_name");
                    String agentAssigned = name.getString("agent_assigned");
                    String orderId = name.getString("order_id");
                    Integer totalQuantity = name.getInt("total_quantity");
                    String orderDate = name.getString("order_date");
                    Integer orderNo = name.getInt("order_no");
                    String schoolYear = name.getString("school_year");
                    String company = name.getString("company");
                    String deliveryDate = name.getString("delivery_date");
                    String orderStatus = name.getString("order_status");
                    Integer grossRevenue = name.getInt("gross_revenue");
                    Integer netRevenue = name.getInt("net_revenue");
                    Integer totalOrdered = name.getInt("total");
                    Integer grandTotalOrdered = name.getInt("grand_total");
                    OrderModel orderModel = new OrderModel(customerName
                            ,agentAssigned
                            ,orderId
                            ,totalQuantity
                            ,orderDate
                            ,orderNo
                            ,schoolYear
                            ,company
                            ,deliveryDate
                            ,orderStatus
                            ,grossRevenue
                            ,netRevenue
                            ,totalOrdered
                            ,grandTotalOrdered);

                    ordersList.add(orderModel);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
    }
}
```

I suspected that integer is not supported by the string during execution.

Comment: Field `order_no` in your json object has value `OR-12345`. So it is either data issue or if that value is valid you need to change type of `orderNo` property in `OrderModel` class to `String`

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting `order_no` to be an Integer and thus written this 
`Integer orderNo = name.getInt("order_no");`
But you are receiving an alphanumeric value for `orderNo` in recycler view.
So either you have to change the type of `orderNo` property of `OrderModel` from `Integer` to `String` or restrict values to `Integer` type only.